# ColdFusion - Illegal HTML character

Tags: xslt, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

```
<xsl:attribute name="title">
   <xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I have the above code in CF 8. The 2nd line works fine but the first line errors. Any reason why? They are literally next to each other. I am completely stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Just a short in the dark: try to remove or change intendation of that line #2 (spaces/tabs whatever you are using).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Think I had a problem with new line in the beginning of XML, but essentially -- there seems to be some nasty non-printable character in your XML.

Comment: Any idea how to sort? Have tried `<title><![CDATA[#item#]]></title>` but no luck

Comment: Can you at least post the error and the code you're using?

Comment: Voted to close, user has not followed up with additional information.